# How to aggregate in pandas including missing rows?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a DataFrame with (id, x) pairs and a list of IDs of interest.

I can get aggregates sum of x per each ID of interest, which I can achieve by `df[['id','x']].groupby('id').agg('sum')`

But in case there are no records for a particular ID it won't show up in the result. How to get zeros for such IDs? In SQL that would be an OUTER JOIN.

Example data:

```
id  x
------
1   10
1   12
2   27
4   49
```

With IDs of interest `[1,2,3,4]` the expected result is:

```
1  22
2  27
3  0
4  49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reindex`

```
In [226]: (df.groupby('id').sum()
             .reindex(range(1, df['id'].max() + 1), fill_value=0)
             .reset_index())
Out[226]:
   id   x
0   1  22
1   2  27
2   3   0
3   4  49
```

Comment: Appreciate! I'm just learning pandas. [reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is the solution indeed.

I was looking to including a manually defined list of ids, so in my case it became: `.reindex( my_list, fill_value=0)`